# Nmake standard output to file

Tags: stdout, nmake, redirectstandardoutput, logfile

I'm looking for a way to write the standard output of my nmake call to a specified file. I tried something like "nmake target > file.log", but this won't work. Moreover I call multiple nmakes from within my MAKEFILE and may use multiple log-files to keep track of the output. I've only found the nmake option to write errors to a file but what's about the standard output.

Is there a simple way to do that (in Windows)?

Comment: it works for me. `nmake target > log.out` produces a file that contains the output of the make session. Can you provide a makefile that produces the behavior you are reporting here?

Answer (score 1):

@Cheeso
I've tried to built simple example and noticed that it doesn't work for me because the MAKEFILE must running in elevated mode. Consider a makefile like this:

```
default:
 REM Test
```

and a batch-file like this:

```
cd /d "%~dp0"
nmake output.log
pause
```

When running the batch-file as administrator it doesn't redirect the stdout to my file and returns an error.

Comment: I'm sure it has something to do with the elevated mode and the `cd /d "%~dp0"` which is needed to run the MAKEFILE directly located besides the batch-file.

Answer (score 0):

`jom` is really picky, and it's made based on `nmake`. Since that's the case, we're probably dealing with the same pickiness.

This works : `jom -j 8 >> build.log`

While this doesn't work : `jom -j 8>>build.log`

Add some whitespace, and you should be good to go. This was incredibly annoying for me too with Qt 5.6.1-1. I even tried using Powershell transcripts, but that ended up being a complete bust.